# How to blind childwindow content to a datagrid in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a datagrid with 4 fields: From, To ,Title ,Message ;and to buttons + and -. When the + button is clicked a childwindow with 3 textboxs From, To,Title a and a richtextbox Message opens what i want do to is : add a new cell with the inserted values after the user clicked in ok (already have ok and cancel and not valid email functions)with the respectives values for ex :the user clicked in + and in the Title  typed a in the From typed a@a.a and in the To typed b@a.a the richtext he just typed a random message after that he clicks in ok  and a new cell is added in the grid with the inserted falues in each colum From a@a.a apears in the To b@a.a and in the Title  aperas a in the Message the message he typed appers
if need the code of this part of the project to make it more easy to understand just say it

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879612/pass-data-to-child-window-in-silverlight-4-using-mvvm